# Batch Split each line into multiples lines

Tags: batch-file, text, split

My txt file looks like:

```
A1;A2;A3
B1;B2
```

I want to split it like:

```
A1;;;A2
A2;;;A3
A3;;;A3
B1;;;B2
B2;;;B2
```

The rule is:  For each line take two adjacent elements and create a new output line with them, for the last element of a line: create also a new output line, but use the element twice.

Here is my try:

```
(
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=;" %%a in (%FilePath%) do (
        for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=;" %%x in (%FilePath%) do (
            echo %%a;;;%%y
        )
    )
)>%FilePath_Final%
```

But it gives the wrong format:

```
A1;;;A2
A1;;;B2
B1;;;A2
B1;;;B2
```

How can I use batch commands to split the lines so that the expected result is obtained?

PS: A1, A2, B1 etc. are just some string examples, I can have various strings

Here is an example of a file content:

```
XB8998901;XB8998900;8051191;24048271;24048270
XB0134812;XB0134810;XB0134801;XB0134800
XB6312701;XB6312700
XB6314201;XB6314200
```

The ouput should look like:

```
XB8998901;;;XB8998900
XB8998900;;;8051191
8051191;;;24048271
24048271;;;24048270
24048270;;;24048270
XB0134812;;;XB0134810
XB0134810;;;XB0134801
XB0134801;;;XB0134800
XB0134800;;;XB0134800
XB6312701;;;XB6312700
XB6312700;;;XB6312700
XB6314201;;;XB6314200
XB6314200;;;XB6314200
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the word "disposal" is correct in this sentence (but I could be wrong). Um, "so that the expected result is obtained"?

Comment: As a rule: For each line take two adjacent elements and create a new output line with them, for the last element of a line: create also a new output line, but use the element twice. Are these rules correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll add it to the description to make it clearer

Comment: R.Omar, somebody answered your question 16 hours ago, and updated it 6 hours ago. How about you provide them with feedback on their proposed solution? instead of seemingly ignoring it.

Comment: I updated my post with the answer I gave. I don't literraly have A and B. It's just examples

Comment: How many 'elements' are there on each line? or What is the maximum number of 'elements' per line? _(your code suggests `4`)_. What characters/character set can/does the file contain? Is the file `CRLF` or `LF` terminated? Can you provide a more realistic example file?

Comment: There is a maximum of 10 elements in each line.
The file can contain letters and numbers.
I don't know how to determine if my file is CRLD or LF terminated.
I gave an example of a file containt in the description above.

Comment: My file is CRLF terminated. I Just figured it out.

Comment: Can you please also provide the expected output from your newly edited example file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "last="
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (old.txt) do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    if defined last echo !last!;;;%%b
    set "last=%%b"
  )
echo !last!;;;!last!
set "last="
))>new.txt
fc new.txt compare.txt
```

old.txt (your example file):

```
XB8998901;XB8998900;8051191;24048271;24048270
XB0134812;XB0134810;XB0134801;XB0134800
XB6312701;XB6312700
XB6314201;XB6314200
```

compare.txt (desired output from your example):

```
XB8998901;;;XB8998900
XB8998900;;;8051191
8051191;;;24048271
24048271;;;24048270
24048270;;;24048270
XB0134812;;;XB0134810
XB0134810;;;XB0134801
XB0134801;;;XB0134800
XB0134800;;;XB0134800
XB6312701;;;XB6312700
XB6312700;;;XB6312700
XB6314201;;;XB6314200
XB6314200;;;XB6314200
```

Output:

```
Vergleichen der Dateien new.txt und compare.txt
FC: Keine Unterschiede gefunden
```

(Translation: `Comparing files new.txt and compare.txt`; `FC: no differences encountered`)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=;" %%a in ('type  pathoffile ^| find "A"') do (set 1=%%a & set 2=%%b & set 3=%%c)
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%a in ('type  pathoffile ^| find "B"') do (set 4=%%a & set 5=%%b)
set n=1
:loop
set /a m=n+1
if "!%n%:~0,1!"=="!%m%:~0,1!" (
  echo !%n%!;;;!%m%! >>filepath_final
) else (
  echo!%n%!;;; >>filepath_final
)
set /a n=n+1
if %m% equ 5 goto :eof 
goto loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But I don't literraly  have A , B, in my txt file.I can have various strings.

Comment: If you use various strings replace them with A and B

Comment: I need these exact strings (that are not constant), that's why i don't want to replace it. It's just examples. I can have: 45TFH56 or 789RTY448 or anything else

Comment: Wasif, I added the repeating of the last element of each list in my post. ex: A3;;;A3 and B2;;;B2